# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_probability' has no attribute 'stats'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I have a Problem with tensorflow-probability, I want to calculate the variance of my tensor using

> tfp.stats.variance(E)

But I am always getting the following error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_probability' has no attribute 'stats'
```

I have searched for hours through the internet and the forum, but nothing helped me, so I am asking the question hoping someone can help me. I am using the tensorflow version: 2.13.0.

And I am using python on a MacBook and visual studio code

When I run pip3 list I get the following:

```
tensorflow                    2.13.0
tensorflow-estimator          2.13.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.33.0
tensorflow-probability        0.20.1
tfp-nightly                   0.22.0.dev20230925
```

Thank you in advance

Best wishes

I have searched for hours through the internet and the forum, but nothing helped me, so I am asking the question hoping someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try Installing the latest version of tfp. I tried with updated version in my local and its working good

```
tensorboard                  2.13.0
tensorboard-data-server      0.7.1
tensorflow                   2.13.0
tensorflow-estimator         2.13.0
tensorflow-intel             2.13.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.31.0
tensorflow-probability       0.21.0
```

Install `pip install --user tensorflow`

Install tfp `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-probability`

To keep it simple, I tried the below code

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

E = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])

variance = tfp.stats.variance(E)

print(variance)
```

Resulted  Output :

```
tf.Tensor(2.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your very fast answer, I tried to install the latest version of tfp (0.20.1), however If I run your code I still get the same error message

Comment: the `tensorflow-probability` latest version is `0.21.0` - you can install using `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-probability`

Comment: Thats what I did, but its still not working, I get the same error message

Comment: I assume you also have `tfp-nightly`. Can you uninstall nightly version and only use the upgraded `tensorflow-probability`.

Comment: Yes, I had tfp-nightly, I uninstalled it and I am using tensorflow-proability (0.21.0), still doesnt work                                                                           `tensorboard                   2.13.0
tensorboard-data-server       0.7.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1
tensorflow                    2.13.0
tensorflow-estimator          2.13.0
tensorflow-intel              0.0.1
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.33.0
tensorflow-probability        0.21.0`